# rails postgres date_time not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am getting a weird error when trying to save a record with a datetime to postgres. Sometimes it works, see the first example. Other times it doesn't work.

```
UPDATE "client_comments" SET "comment" = $1, "conversation_time" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "client_comments"."id" = 2  [["comment", "test2"], ["conversation_time", "2015-03-09 23:42:00.000000"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-16 23:50:32.307101"]]
```

works, no problems!

When I use a form with a

```
<%= f.datetime_select :conversation_time, { :start_year => 2010, :end_year => Date.today.year } %>
```

I click update, params are:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iz/MS9mI3K7H0dg05AFjaiKTudLpuG3ipAtApGbHEQA=", "client_comment"=>{"client_id"=>"1221", "user_id"=>"1", "company_id"=>"MON", "conversation_time(1i)"=>"2015", "conversation_time(2i)"=>"3", "conversation_time(3i)"=>"7", "conversation_time(4i)"=>"19", "conversation_time(5i)"=>"42", "comment"=>"test2"}, "commit"=>"Update Client comment", "id"=>"2"}
```

sql is:

```
UPDATE "client_comments" SET "conversation_time" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "client_comments"."id" = 2  [["conversation_time", "2015-03-08 00:42:00.000000"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-17 00:01:43.611166"]]
```

which causes this exception:

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "conversation_time" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type time without time zone at character 52
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Another weird thing is the hour in this case is 19 but it is trying to set the hour to 00 in the sql, so I dont know what is up with that either.

Here is my schema:

```
# \d+ client_comments
                                                         Table       "public.client_comments"
  Column       |            Type             |                          Modifiers                           | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
  -------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------     --------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                | integer                     | not null default  nextval('client_comments_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 client_id         | integer                     |                                                              | plain    |              | 
 user_id           | integer                     |                                                              | plain    |              | 
 company_id        | integer                     |                                                              | plain    |              | 
 comment           | text                        |                                                              | extended |              | 
 employee_user_id  | integer                     |                                                              | plain    |              | 
 created_at        | timestamp without time zone |                                                              | plain    |              | 
 updated_at        | timestamp without time zone |                                                              | plain    |              | 
 conversation_time | timestamp without time zone |                                                              | plain    |              | 
 Indexes:
"client_comments_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"index_client_comments_on_client_id" btree (client_id)
"index_client_comments_on_company_id" btree (company_id)
"index_client_comments_on_user_id" btree (user_id)
Has OIDs: no
```

rails v 4.1.8
psql (9.3.2)

Comment: I think you need to do some casting.  See this post and search for INTERVAL (re: timestamp without time zone).  http://brendankemp.com/essays/dealing-with-time-zones-using-rails-and-postgres/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is not a perfect answer, but it turns out to be a bug with either rails 4.1 and pg 0.17.1 or them working together. I upgraded to rails 4.2.1 (just came out) and pg 0.18.1 and all is finally well. Note pg 0.81.1 and earlier versions of rails had a bug with blob support, but 4.2.1 seems to have fixed that.